# How to unit test suspend function with callback

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mockito, kotlin-coroutines

I have the following code:

```kotlin
suspend fun initialize(sdk: Sdk) =
    suspendCoroutine<Unit> { continuation ->
        try {
            sdk.initialize(
                callback = { continuation.resume(Unit) },
                onFailure = { error -> continuation.resumeWithException(SdkException(error.message)) })
        } catch (exception: Exception) {
            continuation.resumeWithException(
                SdkException("Crash inside SDK", exception)
            )
        }
    }
```

The Sdk is a third-party library. I'm using `suspendCoroutine` to suspend the coroutine and resume when the sdk finishes initializing.
Everything works fine but when I try to write a unit test like this I get the following `IllegalStateException: This job has not completed yet`. I'm using [mockito-kotlin](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-kotlin) to write the following test:

```kotlin
    @Test
    fun `should initialize sdk correctly`() = runBlockingTest {
        val sdk = mock<Sdk>()

        initializeSdk(sdk)

        verify(sdk).initialize(any(), any())
    }
```

Basically what I want to do is to be able to test the `resume` and `resumeWithException`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I'm not a fan of mocks. If `Sdk` is an interface, you could just provide your own test implementation to perform your tests (for success and error results). You can control exactly when/if the callback is called etc.

If Sdk is a class that you can't control, you could create an interface to abstract the `Sdk` class away, and make your `initialize` method use your own interface instead. However I have to admit this is not ideal.

If you stick with mocking, usually mocking libraries have a way for you to use invocation arguments to mock responses to method calls. With Mockito, it should be something like:

```kotlin
val sdk = mock<Sdk> {
    on { initialize(any(), any()) } doAnswer { invocation ->
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        val successCallback = invocation.arguments[0] as (() -> Unit) // use callback's function type here
        successCallback.invoke()
    }
}
```

(although I'm not an expert in Mockito, so there may be more concise or type-safe ways :D)